# How could I load a class from another class with autoloading

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

How could I load a class (`Connect{}`) from another class (`API{}`) with **composer** `autoloader.php`

**My files hierarchy**

```
main.php
composer.json
src\
------ Database
---------- Connect.php
------ API
---------- API.php
vendor\
------ [...]
```

**Composer autoload**

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    }
```

**main.php**

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
new App\API\API();
```

**API.php**

```
namespace App\API;

class API {
    function __construct (){

        echo '( ';
        new App\Database\Connect; //THE CODE STOPS HERE
        echo ' )';
    }
}
```

**Connect.php**

```
namespace App\Database;

class Connect {
    function __construct () {
        echo('Connecting...');
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't access any class from another, I know that using `global` variables or passing classes in `__construct` may be good solutions, but I need to instantiate new classes from another directly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to put backslash...

```
new App\Database\Connect;
```

should be

```
new \App\Database\Connect;
```

**or** typing `use App\Database\Connect;` outside the class just below the namespace, then construct class as usual `$connect = new Connect()`.

---

### Explanation

Inside class, namespace behavior is like this

```
namespace App\API;
class API {
    function __construct (){
        // WRONG : PHP will look for App\API\App\Database\Connect
        new App\Database\Connect; 

        // RIGHT : PHP will look for App\Database\Connect
        new \App\Database\Connect; 
    }
}
```

or another solution :

```
namespace App\API;
use App\Database\Connect;
class API {
    function __construct (){
        new Connect; 
    }
}
```